# Can I implement a random font selection?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a program that displays some message on a label (using QtDesigner):

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow


class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main1.ui', self)
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.label.setText('Message')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyWidget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This message displays in the selected font in the QtDesigner, StyleSheet of my label:

[image: screenshot]

The question is: What can I do to make this font be randomly selected? Is it possible? (Perfect case: every time i run my program it shows my message in some randomly selected font)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain all the available families through the [`families()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#families) method of [`QFontDatabase`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html), choose one randomly, build a [`QFont`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html) and set it in the QLabel:

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow


class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("main1.ui", self)

        db = QFontDatabase()
        family = random.choice(db.families())
        print(family)
        font = db.font(family, "", 72)
        # also random style:
        # style = random.choice(db.styles(family))
        # font = db.font(family, style, 72)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.label.setText("Message")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```